# Implementing an option menu in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-manifest, oncreateoptionsmenu

How do I implement an option menu in my android application? I tried code from [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) but I get errors. Such as these: **Element menu must be declared**. Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/new_game"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
    android:title="@string/new_game"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
    android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.lucavanraalte.test" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: You put it in the wrong place, don't place it in your Manifest.xml but place it in your (YourActivity).xml where you create your activities layout

Comment: I can't tell whether it's just the way you formatted the code in your question, but any menu files need to have their own `xml` file in the `menus` sub-directory in the `res` folder - it shouldn't be part of the manifest.

Comment: Where do I need to put it, and put what? Do I need to create a new folder? See the image above

Comment: Create a folder in your ***res*** (resources) folder, and name it ***menu***. Than inside that folder create an XML file and place your menu code there. Look at the answers below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your java code, add this `onCreateOptionsMenu` to show optionMenu,

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu); //your file name
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Keep your under res\menu\option_menu folder,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/new_game"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
    android:title="@string/new_game"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
    android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

Now, if you want to set `onOptionsItemSelected` i.e onClick event for that ou can use,

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.new_game:
                //your code
                // EX : call intent if you want to swich to other activity 
                return true;
            case R.id.help:
                //your code
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well the issue is solved but how do I add options? And shouldn't I see a menu logo in my application?

Comment: your options are added now if you follow this code. try running code and inform again.

Comment: I have the menu working. But I want it to be so that can still see the option menu, the three dots I mean! The options are overlapping it. And my buttons are not the color they are in Android Studio, how come? Added an image in my post.

Comment: try adding --- android:orderInCategory="2" no of itemsand ---app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: pop you are getting can not be changed it is system default @Lucafraser

Comment: Okay and what is it that my background image and button colors aren't showing. Buttons are yellow; shows white. Background image is also not to be shown.

Comment: it will be according to theme you have applied OR second option is to make it custom @Lucafraser

Comment: Thank you for appriciation @Lucafraser

Comment: can you help me with something else? Maybe chat? I have some annoying problems with my buttons and images not showing the colors and images I want them to show.

Comment: yes, why not or ask another question so that other users will not be confused reagarding this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103271/discussion-between-amit-vaghela-and-lucafraser).

Answer (score 3):

You should use **`onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)`**

> Initialize the contents of the Activity's standard options menu. You
>   should place your menu items in to menu.
>
> This is only called once, the first time the options menu is
>   displayed. To update the menu every time it is displayed, see
>   onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu).

***onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)*** method which needs to override in Activity class. This creates menu and returns Boolean value. inflate inflates a menu hierarchy from XML resource.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu); // set your file name
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Your **option_menu.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/item_First" 
          android:title="@string/item_First"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/save_menu" 
          android:title="@string/save"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/item_Second"
          android:title="@string/item_First"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

Please check demo **[Android Option Menu Example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-option-menu-example)**

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `menu` folder in the `res` directory and in the menu directory create file named my_menu.xml. In that file write these lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/new_game"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
    android:title="@string/new_game"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item android:id="@+id/help"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
    android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

Then in your Activity, do this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: When adding that 2nd part to my MainActivity.java I get errors such as "Cannot resolve symbol such as Inflater"

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `menu.xml` in directory res->menu like menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/new_game"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
android:title="@string/new_game"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
<item android:id="@+id/help"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

Then you need to create your menu from activity with below code

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.help) {

       //do something
       return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.new_game) {

       //do something
       return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Home");
    menu.add("Profile");
    menu.add("Settings");
    menu.add("Privacy Policy");
    menu.add("Terms of use");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getTitle()=="Home"){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Home option selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if (item.getTitle()=="Profile"){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Profile option selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if (item.getTitle()=="Settings"){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Settings option selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if (item.getTitle()=="Privacy Policy"){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Privacy Policy option selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if (item.getTitle()=="Terms of use"){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Terms of use option selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).